# Bootstrap : Get Image from modal

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal with a bunch of images. The images are selectable and after I click on then i change the modal button text to the image name. However I'd also like to grab the image and display. I have no idea how to do this as I have no experience with javascript.

html modal code:

```
<button type="button" id="modal-btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal">
    Click to launch Image Gallery...
</button>
<div id='div_img_name'></div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image Gallery</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {% for image in images %}
                    <input class="img" type="image" src="{{ image.url }}"
                           height="100" width="130"
                           style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;">
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js for changing button text:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    })
    $(".img").click(function () {
        $("#modal-btn").text($(this).attr('src'));
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

How Can I display the chosen Image in the `div_img_name` div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    })
    $(".img").click(function () {
        var img = $(this).attr('src');
        $("#modal-btn").text(img);
        $('#div_img_name').prepend('<img class="img" type="image" src="' + img + '" height="100" width="130"/>');
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        return false;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This works.But If I click of the modal button again and choose another images, the older image is still there and the new images is added to before it ( so now there are 2 images )

Comment: Solved hte issue using - `$("#div_img_name").empty();` before the `prepend()`